# Shell script - check the syntax

Tags: shell, unix

How to check the correctness of the syntax contained in the ksh shell script without executing it? To make my point clear: in perl we can execute the command:

```
perl -c test_script.pl
```

to check the syntax. Is something similar to this available in ksh?

Answer (score 4):

ksh -n

Most of the Borne Shell family accepts -n. tcsh as well.

Comment: It does not seem to be working. I executed ksh -n test.sh but it did not list out the syntax error which was there in test.sh

Comment: Yes it does work. I'm sure there is no syntax error. If you show us the script we can analyze if your expectations of finding a syntax error are correct.

Comment: Then try with `sh -n script`.  It should work.  However, if your syntax error is in an invalid command name, that would only get caught at run time.  `sh -n` only checks the actual shell syntax.

Comment: Also some errors only show up at run time, even syntax errors. The trouble is that shells reparse each line each time the line executes... a classic "interpreter" behavior. Thus if any meta-characters (' " $, ... often ! ... ) are in a variable used in the line the characters can adversely impact late parsing. The first round of defense is to quote every $ variable, and if reading $*, understand and use the alternate "$@" notation (with the double quotes).

Comment: Jens : yes -n did not catch syntax errors like I changed echo to eco and sh -n did not report any syntax error

Answer (score 1):

I did a small test with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f "buggyScript.sh" ; then
    echo "found this buggy script"
fi
```

Note the missing ] in the if. Now I entered

```
bash -n buggyScript.sh
```

and the missing ] was not detected.

The second test script looked like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f "buggyScript.sh" ]; then
    echo "found this buggy script"
```

Note the missing fi at at end of the if. Testing this with

```
bash -n buggyScript.sh
```

returned

```
buggyScript.sh: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Conclusion:
Testing the script with the n option detects some errors, but by no means all of them. So I guess you really find all error only while executing the script.

Answer (score 1):

The tests that you say failed to detect syntax errors, where not in fact syntax errors...
echo is a command (OK a builtin, but still a command) so ksh/bash are not going to check the spelling/syntax of your command.
Similarly "[" is effectively an alias for the test command, and the *command* expects the closing brace "]" as part of its syntax, not ksh/bash's.
So -n does what it says on the tin, you just haven't read the tin correctly! :-)